# Debian 9: Which package is required to automount USB-drives?

Tags: debian, mount, usb, udev, automounting

I successfully installed Debian 9 (Stretch) together with desktop environment `LXQt`. To keep the system minimal and clean I disabled auto-installation of all recommended and suggested packages via

```
APT::Install-Recommends "0";
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
```

in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10noinstall-recommends`.

However, USB-drives don't get automounted now. The plugged-in USB-mouse as well as keyboard work completely fine. Which package is required to automount USB-drives the usual way to `/media/user/drive`?

---

The package `udev` seems to be installed: CLI-command `dpkg -s udev` displays the following (amongst other things):

```
Package: udev
Status: install ok installed
Breaks: bash-completion, consolekit, ifplugd, ifupdown, joystick, kmod, plymouth, systemd, usb-modeswitch
Conflicts: hal
```

---

The command `lsusb` is detecting all drives, but they do not get automounted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need Udisks and PCManFM: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCManFM#Desktop_management

You might also need Consolekit for the privileges

Comment: Exactly! The package `udisks2` was missing, now everything works fine! Thanks a lot!